# Scikit train_test_split by an indice

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, scipy, classification

I have a `pandas` dataframe indexed by date. Let's assume it from Jan-1 to Jan-30. I want to split this dataset into X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test but I don't want to mix the dates so I want the train and test samples to be divided by a certain date (or index). I'm trying

`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)`

But when I check the values, I see the dates are mixed. I want to split my data as:

`Jan-1 to Jan-24` to train and `Jan-25 to Jan-30` to test (as test_size is 0.2, that makes 24 to train and 6 to test)

How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: you should read [document](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

Comment: if you want top 24 then use `x.head(24)` and for last 6 use `x.tail(6)` no need for `train_test split`

Comment: @Nihal random_state=None doesn't work. Tried that..

Comment: `random_state=None` will take `numpy.random` that's why it won't work

Comment: Are you looking for TimeSeriesSplit? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit

Comment: @Nihal But you wrote to use it (now I see you edited). Anyway, I want to use `train_test_split` with the condition in my post. Thanks

Comment: bro use argument `shuffle=False` and `stratify=None` (in its [document](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html))

Comment: @Nihal Thanks Bro (or Sis, I guess?) :) this works! I first checked the document and I didn't include shuffle. Missed that default was true. Thanks. Answer the question and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, shuffle=False, test_size=0.2, stratify=None)
```

don't use `random_state=None` it will take `numpy.random`

in [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) its mentioned that use `shuffle=False` along with `stratify=None`

Answer (score 1):

Try using [TimeSeriesSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#time-series-split):

```
X = pd.DataFrame({'input_1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
                  'input_2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]},
                 index=[pd.datetime(2018, 1, 1),
                        pd.datetime(2018, 1, 2),
                        pd.datetime(2018, 1, 3),
                        pd.datetime(2018, 1, 4),
                        pd.datetime(2018, 1, 5),
                        pd.datetime(2018, 1, 6)])
y = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

Which results in `X` being

```
           input_1  input_2
2018-01-01       a        1
2018-01-02       b        2
2018-01-03       c        3
2018-01-04       d        4
2018-01-05       e        5
2018-01-06       f        6
```

```
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=3)
for train_ix, test_ix in tscv.split(X):
    print(train_ix, test_ix)
```

```
[0 1 2] [3]
[0 1 2 3] [4]
[0 1 2 3 4] [5]
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I want. @Nihal answered my question, it's using `shuffle=False`